# How would I store mouse coordinates on an online server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i’m pretty new to the server side of programming, and i have have some questions. First off, my project is built in javascript and node.js. How it works is it sends mouse coordinates to the server, and redraws them onto everyone else’s client. This means there is no way for new clients to view what was previously drawn. How could new viewers see what was previously drawn? I imagine i would store mouse coordinates with it’s color in a database, and load that it. I’m not sure where to start on any of this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks y’all :)

EDIT: so i did some more research, and others say a better option may be taking an image of the current canvas, and uploading it to the server, then just showing it to the new user. i have figured out how to save the canvas, just dont know how to get it on any type of server. sorry for being so helpless lol. thanks yall :)

**SKETCH.JS**

```
var socket;
var color;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 800);
  background(51);
  frameRate(100);

  socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('mouse', newDrawing);

  color = {
    r: random(255),
    g: random(255),
    b: random(255),
  }
}

function newDrawing(data) {
  noStroke();
  fill(data.color.r, data.color.g, data.color.b);
  ellipse(data.x, data.y, 36, 36)
}

function mouseDragged() {
  console.log('Sending: ' + mouseX + ',' + mouseY)

  var data = {
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY,
    color: color
  }

  socket.emit('mouse', data);

  noStroke();
  fill(data.color.r, data.color.g, data.color.b);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 36, 36)
  ellipse(15,25,20,20);
  fill(255);
  textSize(10);
  text('your color:',10,10);


}

function draw() {}

function keyTyped() {
  if (key === 'p') {
    color = {
      r: random(255),
      g: random(255),
      b: random(255)
    }
  }
}
```

**SERVER.JS**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("My socket server is running");

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
  console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id);

  socket.on('mouse', mouseMsg);

  function mouseMsg(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('mouse', data);
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

sorry im so helpless yall. yall's help is great :)

Comment: Do you absolutely need to store the data or do you just want live streaming to other clients?

Comment: it’s already being live streamed to the other clients. but anytime someone new joins, they don’t see what was previously done by everyone else.

Comment: How much data is being sent / needs to be stored for a 'session'? Also have you thought about how the new clients will receive the drawings (full playback, snapshots, individual segments etc)? And does it need to be persistent after a session? You could use either a database or in memory datastore.

Comment: it’s just mouse coordinates and an rgb value. not much at all

Comment: Just design your data structure as an object and make some global variables in your node.js script to store them in RAM. No need to write to disk.

Comment: @Mason Thomas go for in memory datastore. For example Redis or just store in variables with node.

Comment: @RickyMo ok i promise im trying my hardest, but im so lost. so like, what? imma edit my question to include and maybe yall could give me the best approach. sorry again i feel so bad lol. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some little additions to your server.js should do the trick.

1. Declare a variable to store the mouse data. I use an object as an key-value map in this example.
2. When receive mouse data from socket, store the data into the variable. `socket.id` can be used as an object key so you only store one data for each socket. `usersCurrentMouseData` will look like `{socketId1:mouseData1, socketId2:mouseData2, socketId3:mouseData3, ...}`
3. When new socket connection comes, use a loop to emit all stored mouse data to it.

.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var usersCurrentMouseData = {};    //Declare a variable to store the mouse data.

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("My socket server is running");

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
  console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id);

  socket.on('mouse', mouseMsg);
  for(var socketId in usersCurrentMouseData)  //loop through all mouse data stored
  {
      socket.emit('mouse',usersCurrentMouseData[socketId]);    //emit the stored mouse data to this new connection only.
  }

  function mouseMsg(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('mouse', data);
    userCurrentMouseData[socket.id] = data  //store the mouse data per socket
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

EDIT: To store all points, simply use a array and no need to map per socket.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var usersCurrentMouseData = [];    //Declare a variable to store the mouse data.

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("My socket server is running");

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
  console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id);

  socket.on('mouse', mouseMsg);
  for(var data of usersCurrentMouseData)  //loop through all mouse data stored
  {
      socket.emit('mouse',data);    //emit the stored mouse data to this new connection only.
  }

  function mouseMsg(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('mouse', data);
    userCurrentMouseData.push(data)  //store the mouse data 
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the amazing response. it is all working great, except for the fact that it only stores one point per user. From what i tell, it only shows the last point the user drew. thank you for your amazing help so far though :)

Comment: @MasonThomas Oh I made a wrong extra assumption myself. I edited the answer to show the way to store all points. Though if storing all points is what you want, data size may get large eventually. Writing to database on disk may be necessary if the data size get really large.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the redis it is a in-memory data structure it is very fast and would be good to store whatever you want to store.

Here is documentation:
https://redis.io/documentation

It supports lists,Hash maps, and other Data structures.In your case you can use hash maps.

For canvas you have make function to draw on canvas like this:

```
 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',(e) =>{
  if(drag) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    let oldx = this.X;
    let oldy = this.Y;
    ctx.moveTo(oldx, oldy);
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.lineWidth = penWidth;
    ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX , e.offsetY );
    ctx.strokeStyle = penColor;
    ctx.stroke();
    this.X = e.offsetX;
    this.Y = e.offsetY;
 }
})
```

You should store coordinates and with the help of socket.io emit the event to other clients on server.for undo and redo part you have store the full stroke or you can say an array of coordinate for every line on canvas and when you want to render that stroke you can make a function like this:

```
 function rerender(strokes){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
for(let i=0 ; i<strokes.length ; i++){
    console.log(strokes.length);
    for(let j=0 ; j<strokes[i].length ; j++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(strokes[i][j].oldx,strokes[i][j].oldy);
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.lineWidth = strokes[i][j].width+1;
        ctx.lineTo(strokes[i][j].x,strokes[i][j].y);
        ctx.strokeStyle = strokes[i][j].color;
        ctx.stroke();
        strokes[i][j].oldx = strokes[i][j].x;
        strokes[i][j].oldy = strokes[i][j].y;
    }
}

}
```